# I don't understand this Java while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm confused about this while loop. If the condition is **true** then repeat; if **false** then end the loop. Is that right?

```java
int a = in.nextInt();
int num;
int highestDigit = 0;

while (a > 0) {
    int digit = a % 10;
    if (digit > highestDigit) {
        highestDigit = digit;
    }
    a /= 10;
}

System.out.println(highestDigit);
```

However, the condition is true so it would print the highest digit over and over again. But the code stops when it find the highest digit.

*input: 214  output: 4*

Comment: `a /= 10` happens each turn through the loop, making `a` smaller until it is zero; then the loop ends.

Comment: Time to learn how to debug

Comment: 'println' is outside the while loop. What makes you think it will print anything more than once ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a decent Java IDE like e.g. Eclipse, use its debugger and single-step through the program, closely watching the variables.

Or, to get an even deeper understanding of such a program, take a long sheet of paper and simulate the program in your brain (current instruction plus variable values resulting from that instruction):

```
instruction                    a     highestDigit   digit   remark
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int a = in.nextInt();         214        -            -
int highestDigit = 0;         214        0            -
while (a > 0) {               214        0            -     is true: enter loop
int digit = a % 10;           214        0            4
if (digit > highestDigit) {   214        0            4     is true: enter block
highestDigit = digit;         214        4            4
a /= 10;                       21        4            4
while (a > 0) {                21        4            -     is true: enter loop
int digit = a % 10;            21        4            1
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use a debugger that can be really hopeful, and then I changed your code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
       int a = sc.nextInt();
        int num ;
        int highestDigit = 0;

        while (a > 0) {
            int digit = a % 10;
            if (digit > highestDigit) {
                highestDigit = digit;
            }
            a /= 10;
            System.out.println("highestDigit is : " + highestDigit);
        }

        System.out.println(highestDigit);
        }
}
```

I think if you run the code which I mentioned you'll get your answer.

You didn't see the highestDigit again and again because you are using `System.out.print` after the while loop, so it just print the highestDigit which is founded after for loop.

Comment: I  ran your code and it only print three of this "highestDigit is : 4 highestDigit is : 4 highestDigit is : 4" why is it only three?

Comment: It depends on 'int a', I mean it's dynamic and it'll change with the input which you entered.